# Forms as modal windows

Tags: drupal, module, dialog, cck

i got a form and i want to show it as window dialog and able to submit it via dialog
how i do that? what module i need?

also, how can i make that i get unique class for each form element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal has a module for [modals](http://drupal.org/project/modalframe).
As for the unique class names in your form, [this article](http://data.agaric.com/node/2398) may be helpful.

Comment: is there any examples for the modalframe

Comment: Just realized I wanted to link you to the popups module, the modalframe module is if you want to make completely custom modal windows, if your just looking for something lightbox-esque, then this should be more down your alley http://drupal.org/project/popups

There's a screen cast on there that shows it off a little bit, but other then that I don't really know of any other great examples of it in action.

Answer (score 3):

The [Popups module](http://drupal.org/project/popups) is awesome for this.

You can easily target a page (with your form), and it puts the content of the page in the popup. It opens it similarly to a lightbox, but it does not open a new browser window.